# Redirect to URL with query string

Tags: redirect, ee-1.12.0.2

In my module, after execution of my script, I need to make a redirect to a page with a query string in the URL.

Here is what I have:

```
$redirectUrl = 'http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index';
$redirectArgs = array('test' => '1');
$this->_redirect($redirectUrl, $redirectArgs);
```

I also tried:

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl, $redirectArgs)->sendResponse();
```

Both methods throw an error: There has been an error processing your request

What I expect is to be redirected to `http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index?test=1`

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

**Edit:**

As suggested, I have tried:

```
$redirectUrl = 'http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index?test=1';
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
```

No error, but nothing happens. I am not in a controller.

**Edit 2:**

I ended up using:

```
$redirectUrl = 'http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index?test=1';
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse();
```

This works as expected! Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just build the url like this?

```
 $redirectUrl = 'http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index?test=1';
```

the second parameter of `setRedirect` is for the redirect code (301, 302).

If you want to build the url internaly you can try this:

```
$redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('_query'=>'test=1'));
```

Comment: And then? `$this->_redirect($redirectUrl);` ?

Comment: @MrUpsidown. `_redirect` if you are in a controller. If you are somewhere else: `Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);`

Comment: Nevermind. Adding `->sendResponse()` at the end did the job!

Comment: @MrUpsidown. Sorry. I forgot about `sendResponse`

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this is like this.

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('urlpost/index/response', array('_secure'=>true,'_query'=>'string1=417'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another URL with query parameters, you can do that like this:

```
$redirectUrl = 'http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index';
$query_parameters = array(
                '_query'=> array(
                    'test' => '1',
                    'test'=>'2'
                )
            );

$this->_redirect($redirectUrl, $query_parameters);
```

This will redirect you to:
http://magento.local/en_en/shop/index?test=1&test=2

Answer (score 0):

If you ended up here from google, are using a controller and want to redirect to another preserving the arguments you can use:

```
$this->_redirect('module/controller/action', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

Where `module`, `controller` and `action` can be replaced by `*` to preserve it's value.
Another action in same controller:

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/anotherAction', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

Same action name, sibling controller:

```
$this->_redirect('*/sibling/*', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
```

And so on...